# simple facebook like on webpage

Tags: html, facebook-like

I would like to add a simple button on my page that would do the "Like" for my page. But I also **do not want** the full functionality of the facebook developers like box because it messes up my layout. And I am not too good at CSS. So I simply want to add the button, the visitor clicks on it, and the "Like" action is performed without adding anything to the layout.
Is this doable?

```
<div class="rss"><a href="#"><img src="images/rss_2.gif" alt="rss" width="17" height="17" border="0" /></a>You can like us on facebook</div>
```

and in the style.css I have the rss class like this:

```
.rss { width:210px; float:left; text-align:left; font:normal 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#737373; padding:15px 5px 5px 0; margin:0; }
.rss img { float:right; margin:0 3px; padding:0; }
```

So, something like above.
I did try the facebook developers way but it pushes down my entire page after more likes are added. The widget they provide, display pics of who liked the page and other info that I do not care about.

Please help.

Comment: _“The widget they provide, display pics of who liked the page and other info that I do not care about.”_ – well then disable the “Show faces” checkbox when using the code creator Facebook provides (D’oh!), and set the Layout Style to “button count” or “box count” – this is as small of a like button as you can get.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out after posting the question. However since you answered me first, please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*“The widget they provide, display pics of who liked the page and other info that I do not care about.”* – well then disable the “Show faces” checkbox when using the code creator Facebook provides, and set the Layout Style to “button count” or “box count” – this is as small of a like button as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

To *like*, a user first needs to verify your app. So it's not possible without Facebook Developers code and stuff.

However, you might want to give the *Share Dialog* a try: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/share-links/